# Adding an attribute to GFF3 file

Tags: python, sequence-annotation, gff3, gffutils

I failed to add `Note=Gene description` to mRNA attribute with the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import click
import gffutils
import gffutils.gffwriter as gffwriter

@click.command()
@click.option('--gff3', help="Provide GFF3 file", required=True)
@click.option('--keep', help="Keep GFF3 file", required=True)
@click.option('--reject', help="Reject GFF3 file", required=True)
def run(gff3, keep, reject):
    #db = gffutils.create_db(gff3, dbfn='data/test.db', force=True, keep_order=True, merge_strategy='merge',
    #                        sort_attribute_values=True)

    db = gffutils.FeatureDB('data/test.db', keep_order=True)
    for gene in db.features_of_type('gene', order_by='start'):
        print(gene)
        for i in db.children(gene, featuretype='mRNA', order_by='start'):
            print(i)
            print(i.id)
            print(i.attributes['Note']=["Gene description"])
            db.update([i])
```

I got the following error:

```
File "/projects/bioinf-scripts/mod_braker_gff3.py", line 20
    print(i.attributes['Note']=["Gene description"])
         ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a few lines of your input gff file that we can use for testing.

Comment: But why are you printing it? Shouldn't you first add the attribute (`i.attributes['Note']=["Gene description"]`) and _then_ print it `print(i.attributes['Note'])`? I don't know gffutils, but it seems strange to print something before setting it.

Comment: Thank you it works now.

Comment: @user977828 Please post the corrected code as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the attribute before setting it, that's why it's complaining. So instead of this:

```
    print(i.attributes['Note']=["Gene description"])
```

Set it first and *then* print:

```
i.attributes['Note']=["Gene description"]
print(i)
```